# How to structure my iOS code?

Tags: ios, code-structure

I have quite a complex setup, and am looking for advice in how to structure my code. What I'm trying to do is something similar to twitter when you press one of a users images and can swipe through them. This is what I have at the moment:

- A `UIViewController` subclass that gathers data from a server, and passes it to a `UITableViewController` subclass through a variable called `theData`
- This `UITableViewController` subclass also gathers more data as the users scrolls to the bottom of the table view and appends it to `theData` (i.e. uses pagination). This `UITableViewController` subclass is reused throughout the app so that data from a different source can be passed to it.
- When a user clicks on a `UITableViewCell`, a `UIWindow` is created which has a `UIPageViewController` inside it. The window uses the `UITableViewController` as a delegate to access `theData`, and passes the `theData` from the delegate to the `UIPageViewController` in a variable called `pageData`
- Each page of the `UIPageViewController` is a `UIViewController` that loads images from the `pageData`

The next stage is to do pagination as the user swipes to the end of the `pageData` in the `UIPageViewController`. However I don't think my code is structured well enough to reuse the pagination code from the `UITableViewController`. Please could someone give me advice on how to improve this code structure?

Thank you

**EDIT**

The `UIViewController` in the first bullet point does more than just downloading data (it has other views within it).

I use a `UIWindow` to encapsulate the `UIPageViewController` because I want it to expand from the frame of the `UITableViewCell` and "take over" the full screen - covering the status bar.

Comment: You don't need to create a `UIWindow`, there is already one, you just instantiate a new `UIViewController` or a subclass of it and present it/push it on the navigation stack.

I don't think we can help much, since we don't have an idea of how much your your code is "not structured" to present a solution

Comment: This might be more applicable for Programmers or Code Review

Comment: There's a much easier solution. Go to github (or other similar site) and search and find one of the many existing libraries you can use for photo browsing.

Comment: Good question! I am looking forward to read wise answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to create simple service which you can use for communication with the server. You don't need View controller for that.

Further more you can create static methods that will give you `theData` without passing it all over the application.

Regarding the swipe, you can take 3 users in an array, and corresponding to scroll, load additional one, and release unnecessary one. That would help you with memory usage ( if users swipes through 50 or more users ).

Instead of `UIWindow`, create simply segue from `UITableViewController` to DetailView, or in your situation, `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your answer! I've updated my answer to give some more info about the use of the `UIViewController`/`UIwindow`. When you say service, would this be a separate class/public functions that interact with the server?

Comment: For uiwindow - you still don't need it. You will have another view controller to show data, and you can select to hide whatever you want. You want be inside the cell.
For the service - yes, you can create simple NSObject that will take care of communication with the server, that way you will have separate logic for the fetching data and you can reuse it wherever you want without copying the code.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you explain a little more/link me to an article about how static methods can access `theData`? If `theData` is stored in an instance of a class, how would a static method access this?

Comment: well you access them as normal properties, e.g. : self.singleton.theData. You could create singleton class: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/ and reuse same attribute over and over again.